# WebcamJS - Função não funciona às vezes

Tags: javascript

Tenho essa função javascriptt, que é quando tira a foto da webcam, ela funciona, mas tem horas que a parte "webcam.snap()" não funciona. 
Não entendo porque, tem horas que ele funciona, e tem horas que não, ele não retorna nenhum erro no console.
Segue a parte do código :

```js
function take_snapshot() {
  document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML = '<h1>Realizando Upload da Foto...</h1>';
  webcam.snap();
  document.getElementById('<%=btnFechaPopWebCam.ClientID%>').click();
}
```

Tanto que ele chega a realizar o click do FechaPopWebCam, mas nem sempre ele realiza a função do webcam.snap();
E aqui é onde eu chamo a função take_snapshot()

```html
<input type="button" value="Capturar" class="btn btn-default" onclick="take_snapshot();" />
```

Algo estranho que acontece, é que se eu coloco o breakpoint ele sempre funciona certinho, mas quando eu não coloco, as vezes ele não funciona.

Utilizei este [link](http://leonelfraga.com/neomatrixtech/posts/2012/04/capturando-a-imagem-de-uma-webcam-em-paginas-asp-net-salvando-o-cadastro-em-banco-de-dados.html) como referência.

Comment: Por favor, coloque um [mcve] que exiba o problema.

Comment: Foi atualizado, coloquei como chamo a função take_snapshot(), conforme explicado nem sempre a função webcam.snap funciona. Ele pula ela, mas funciona o click do button logo em seguida.

Comment: Um EMCV precisa de um pouco mais do que isso. Do jeito que está não dá pra entendermos qual é o problema porque não dá pra reproduzir. Leia a página do [mcve] caso não saiba o que é isso.

Comment: Acontece que as vezes a função webcam.snap() funciona, e as vezes não. Utilizo essa biblioteca: https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/blob/master/webcam.js

Comment: Poste um código funcional para que possamos testar, só da maneira que esta não sabemos como configurou o `webcam`

Comment: Essa biblioteca que está usando está em modo de manutenção e tem mais de 90 bugs em aberto. O próprio ReadMe do projeto sugere outras bibliotecas.

Comment: http://leonelfraga.com/neomatrixtech/posts/2012/04/capturando-a-imagem-de-uma-webcam-em-paginas-asp-net-salvando-o-cadastro-em-banco-de-dados.html Utilizei esse link como referência.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Segundo a documentação](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/blob/master/DOCS.md#snapping-a-picture:), você precisa passar uma função callback como parâmetro a ser executada depois do `snap`.

> To snap a picture, just call the Webcam.snap() function, passing in a callback function. The image data will be passed to your function as a Data URI, which you can then display in your web page, or submit to a server. Example:

```
Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
    document.getElementById('my_result').innerHTML = '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
} );
```

Comment: Andre, eu salvo direto no banco de dados, neste caso não seria se eu fosse salvar em um diretório ? Atualizei a pergunta, com o link que utilizei como referência.

Comment: Está usando o JS fornecido por ele no fim do artigo? Está setando o hook?

Comment: Sim, estou utilizando o mesmo,  e estou referenciando no inicio da página.